# double include url schema in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls

Is it acceptable to use two includes for the same base url routing schema?

e.g. - I have allauth installed which uses `r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')`

and I want to extend this further with my own app, which extends the `allauth` urls even further.

An example of this would be `accounts/profile` or some other extension of the base `accounts/` url.

Is it fine to do the following?

`r'^accounts/', include('myapp.urls')`

In additon to:

`r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')`

As far as I can tell both will just be included with the base url routing schema and it will just look for the allauth urls first?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is perfectly fine.

Django will look for a matching url in the first one, and if it doesn't find it, it will move on to the next one.